# How to *extract* latitud and longitude greedily in Pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas like this:

```
        id          loc
 40     100005090   -38.229889,-72.326819   
 188    100020985   ut: -33.442101,-70.650327   
 249    10002732    ut: -33.437478,-70.614637   
 361    100039605   ut: 10.646041,-71.619039    \N
 440    100048229   4.666439,-74.071554
```

I need to extract the gps points. I first ask for a contain of a certain regex (found here in SO, see below) to match all cells that have a "valid" lat/long value. However, I also need to `extract` these numbers and either put them on a series of their own (and then call split on the comma) or put them in two new pandas series. I have tried the following for the extraction part:

`ids_with_latlong["loc"].str.extract("[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$")`

but it looks, because of the output, that the reg exp is not doing the matching greedily, because I get something like this:

```
    0   1            2      3   4           5   6       7    8
    40  38.229889   .229889 NaN 72.326819   NaN 72  NaN 72  .326819
    188 33.442101   .442101 NaN 70.650327   NaN 70  NaN 70  .650327
```

Obviously it's matching more than I want (I would just need cols 0, 1, and 4), but simply dropping them is too much of a hack for me to do. Notice that the extract function also got rid of the +/- signs at the beginning. If anyone has a solution, I'd really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HYRY's answer looks pretty good to me.  This is just an alternate approach that uses built in pandas methods rather than a regex approach.  I think it's a little simpler to read though I'm not sure if it will be sufficiently general for all your cases (it works fine on this sample data though).

```
df['loc'] = df['loc'].str.replace('ut: ','')
df['lat'] = df['loc'].apply( lambda x: x.split(',')[0] )
df['lon'] = df['loc'].apply( lambda x: x.split(',')[1] )

          id                    loc         lat         lon
0  100005090  -38.229889,-72.326819  -38.229889  -72.326819
1  100020985  -33.442101,-70.650327  -33.442101  -70.650327
2   10002732  -33.437478,-70.614637  -33.437478  -70.614637
3  100039605   10.646041,-71.619039   10.646041  -71.619039
4  100048229    4.666439,-74.071554    4.666439  -74.071554
```

As a general suggestion for this type of approach you might think about doing in in the following steps:

1) remove extraneous characters with `replace` (or maybe this is where the regex is best)

2) split into pieces

3) check that each piece is valid (all you need to do is check that it's a number although you could take an extra step that it falls into the number range of being a valid lat or lon)

Comment: yes, this is more or less what I'm looking for (rather than the regex approach). However, your method throws the following warning:

`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Being new to Pandas, I'm not sure what to do with that, even though the documentation seems clear, I can't figure out how to use `loc` here.

Comment: Gosh, I'm not sure why you got warning there.  I didn't get it and can't see that it would be a problem here (and the message doesn't necessarily imply the command didn't work, you just have to double check that it did).  As a side note, you might want to change the name of the column, since it potentially conflicts with the `loc` method.  I.e. you'll be OK with `df['loc']` but not `df.loc` for referring to the 'loc' column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?:)` to ignore the group:

```
df["loc"].str.extract(r"((?:[\+-])?\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*((?:[\+-])?\d+\.\d+)")
```